# How to grant system permissions while writing flutter integration tests?

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

I am writing flutter integration tests https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction

I can find and tap on my widgets perfectly fine but the problem arises when I have to click the system widgets to grant permissions in order to continue and test the remaining flow.

For example:
I tap a button then have to grant location permissions. At this moment the screen as below is shown
[image]

This screen is shown by the system and I have no key or way how to tap "While using the app".

Also the system screen might change between devices like ios and android and the text might be different as well.

What is the best practice to solve this issue? I am blocked from testing the remaining screens that use the required permissions..

**What I tried so far?**
I tried to grant the permissions manually for Android as a start but did not work

```
Future<void> grantRequiredAppPermissions() async {
  if (!Platform.isAndroid) {
    return;
  }

  const appPackageName = 'my.package';
  print(
      'We are going to manually grant the required permissions to the android package $appPackageName');

  final Map<String, String> envVars = Platform.environment;
  String adbPath = join(
    envVars['ANDROID_SDK_ROOT'] ?? envVars['ANDROID_HOME']!,
    'platform-tools',
    Platform.isWindows ? 'adb.exe' : 'adb',
  );

  print('Using adb at $adbPath');

  final permissions = [
    'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE',
    'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE',
    'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION',
    'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
  ];

  for (final permission in permissions) {
    await Process.run(
        adbPath, ['shell', 'pm', 'grant', appPackageName, permission]);
  }
}
```

I was calling that function in my `app/integration_test/driver.dart`

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test_driver_extended.dart';

import 'helpers/grant_required_permissions.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await grantRequiredAppPermissions();
  await integrationDriver();
}
```

but did not help at all. Also it is not a proper solution because even if it was going to work, would work only for android and i test also on ios devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the testing framework patrol https://pub.dev/packages/patrol

See the documentation here: https://patrol.leancode.co/

It let's you interact with the native ui like this:

```
await $.native.grantPermissionWhenInUse();
await $.native.grantPermissionOnlyThisTime();
await $.native.denyPermission();
```